# Javascript: implement single exit point from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I am wondering if there is a clean way of implementing single exit point from a function in Javascript. In plain C one could simply use `goto` ([Linux kernel - example source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/164c09978cebebd8b5fc198e9243777dbaecdfa0/fs/dlm/main.c#L26)).

At the first sight one can use `for, break and labels` and `exceptions`.

#### 1. For and labels

```
var retCode = 0;
single_exit:
for(var done=true;done;done=false)
{
    retCode = 1;
    break single_exit;
}
if(retCode !=0)
{
    console.log('error happened. exiting');
    return;
}
```

#### 2. Exceptions

```
function SomeError () {
    this.retcode = 1;
}

SomeError.prototype = new Error();
try{
    if(someThing)
        throw new SomeError();
}
catch(e) {
  if (e instanceof SomeError) {
    return e.retcode;
  } else {
    throw e; 
  }
}
```

Are there any other(nicer) ways to handle this situation?

Comment: Right now, the question looks rather vague. What's the precise use case ? At first sight this looks like an anti-pattern used to deal with badly designed code but maybe you can explain where you intent to use that ?

Comment: @dystroy if there are errors that must stop the execution of the function : `if(err) return;` I would have multiple ways of exiting from that function. I would like to have just one if it is possible.

Comment: A single exit point isn't universally accepted as a good pattern.  If, for logging reasons, you need a single exit point you can wrap a complex function inside of simpler one and do the logging that way.

Comment: It's also possible to define a small function in the one where you can fail and call that function at exit.

Comment: but in the complex function there could be multiple steps like validating input parameters and other stuff. If these steps fails I don't want to continue the execution of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uses promises.

Something like:

`doSomething().then(
   function() { 
     doSomethingElse().then(
        function(){
          doYetAnotherThing()
        })
     }); 
  return 42;`

where doSomething, doSomethingElse and doYetAnotherThing represent the individual steps that could 'break' (where break now means 'return a promise that is marked as failed). Each of them should return a promise.  To make the code flatter you could alternatively do promise-chaining ([here's a good video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-chained-promises), in the context of Angular but you can ignore that part)

Answer (score 2):

I think that @Robert Levy has a very good point. A nice way of treating single exit point would imply promises:

Using `q` module from nodejs one can write:

```
var Q = require('q');
Q.fcall(function(){

})
.then(function(){

})
.then(function(){

})
.catch(function(err){
    //log them
})
.done(function(){
    do other stuff
})
```

Comment: the `then` calls need to be nested, not serial.  Otherwise, all of the `then`s will execute if `fcall` succeeds regardless of what happens in the preceeding `then`s.  Also, nesting will let you do asynchronous stuff within each `then` if desired.  It does make the code uglier though.

Comment: @RobertLevy I don't think I see a problem here. If each `then function` creates it's own promise I think it is ok. I wrote a simple example that shows that even first call succeeds and other `then's` fails it fails where it shouuld fail. http://pastebin.com/QmgQCs0u . On the official page it says that nesting is equivalent with flattening: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: Indeed, it looks like that's a cool feature of Q which I haven't worked with before.  Here, have an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem arises in a large function where you don't want to repeat operations like releasing resources.

Then a solution might be to define a simple function :

```
function yourFunction(){
     var resource = thing();
     function quit(){
         resource.release();
     }
     ... lot of code ...
     if (...) return quit();
     ...
}
```

Another solution might be to wrap your function in another one :

```
function bigFunWrapper(){
    var resource = thing();
    yourFunction();
    resource.release(); 
}
```

This solution, If you don't call it from multiple place, can be rewritten as an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) :

```
(function(){
    var resource = thing();
    yourFunction();
    resource.release(); 
})();
```

Depending on the precise use case, there's probably a better solution.

Comment: You can make `yourFunction` an innerfunction of `bigFunWrapper`.  I find it cleaner and makes sure that `yourFunction` is never called by mistake.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I think you're referring to my first solution, aren't you ?

Comment: Mm.. most likely.  My eyes got caught on the same function name in both cases and mentally linked the code blocks together.  Never mind me.

Comment: In the second sollution you could also use a self executing anonymous function. Instead of yourFunction() write 
(function(){ ...do something... })();

Answer (score 0):

Now, before I answer this question, let me clearly state:

I consider this an ANTI-PATTERN! Not to be used, but an interesting approach to part of your question.

```
var returnCode = null;
do {
  // Do calculation
  if (condition) break;

  // do calculation
  if (condition2) break;



} while (false);
return returnCode;
```

Explanation:  A `do...while` loop must run at least one time.  The `false` condition makes sure it only runs once.  The `break` exits the loop and jumps to the bottom.

Comment: I know about this way and it's quite similar with my version `for(var done=true;done;done=false)`